# Are driver global variables located in kernel process address space?

Tags: c, kernel, driver

Why can i access driver global varialbe both at kernel process(DriverEntry)
and in user processes (PreOperation io callbacks for instance).

Comment: surely a PreOperation IO callback doesn't run in userspace.

Comment: @nos.. If i put a breakpoint at PreOperation for Write and call: 0: kd> !process
PROCESS ffffe000030eb080
    SessionId: 1  Cid: 0b0c    Peb: 7ff6555af000  ParentCid: 07c8
    DirBase: 129cda000  ObjectTable: ffffc00002dcd540  HandleCount: <Data Not Accessible>
    Image: notepad.exe
    VadRoot ffffe00003342b30 Vads 76 Clone 0 Private 386. Modified 12. Locked 0.
    DeviceMap ffffc000027a5620

Comment: So it is Notepad process not System(kernel) process

Comment: Notepad.exe performed a system call and you're in kernel space, on behalf of notepad.